# Instance type changes when i receive a json

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a question regarding data type in typescript and angular 2. I created a class in typescript

```
export class product{
    public id:number;
    public name:string;
    public status:boolean;
    constructor(){}
}
```

And I instantiate this class for use inside my system.

```
private product:Product = new Product();
```

When I'm using the product instance inside the typescript it really is of the type product. the problem is my backend is in php/laravel. My backend returns me an object in json when I get a product in server. And I assign this json to my product instance.

```
this.productService.getProductById(id).subscribe(result => {
      this.product = result;
});
```

But the instance ceases to be of the type product and happens to be of the type object. I realize this when I give a console.log before and after assigning

```
this.productService.getProductById(id).subscribe(result => {
       console.log(this.product);   
       this.product = result;
       console.log(this.product); 
});
```

result in console:

```
Imagens {}
Object {id: 1, namme: "test", status: true…}
```

This is a problem. I wanted to work with data typing.Another detail is that the server response inserts property into product if my server returns a property it did not have in the class. I want to have the security of the instance of my class only have the attributes that have been defined in the class.

Anyone know how to solve this question?

Comment: when you assign the object you fetched from the server like this, `this.product = result`, it gets overwritten. You can create an interface for the object you're getting from the server and have an intialize method in your class.

Comment: Thank you very much, my friend!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning

```
this.product = result;
```

does not set the prototype on `result`. If you want `result` to be of type `Product`, I'd recommend adding a constructor (that takes a data object) to `Product`, and calling it:

```
this.product = new Product(result);
```

For small classes, I'd likely just write the constructor manually:

```
public class Product {
    foo: int;
    constructor(obj) {
        this.foo = obj.foo;
    }
}
```

but that requires duplicating each field as an assignment. It works, though!

Personally, I'm using a custom `assign` to do this for me, in the format:

```
constructor(obj) {
    assign(this, obj, {}, {})
}
```

It basically just performs something similar `Object.assign` to get the job done, and some extra arguments in case I have to instantiate something `new` inside the product.

Comment: I liked your answer.

Comment: Friend, another question I have. And when I go to the server to fetch several products. What is the best way to assign an array of json to an array of specific objects?

Comment: JSON.parse(arr).map(each => new Thing(each))

Comment: @uber5001 you are fantastic. I also had this doubt! I was following the topic. thank

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I would do:

1. Make an interface that reflects what you get back from the server:

   ```
   interface IProduct {
       id: number;
       name: string;
       status: boolean;
   }
   ```
2. Allow the constructor of Product to take this in:

   ```
   class Product {
       public id: number;
       public name: string;
       public status: boolean;
       constructor(copyFrom?: IProduct) {
           if (copyFrom != null) {
               this.id = copyFrom.id;
               this.name = copyFrom.name;
               this.status = copyFrom.status;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: hum interesting! I'll follow this line you suggested. Thank you very much, my friend!

Comment: Friend, another question I have. And when I go to the server to fetch several products. What is the best way to assign an array of json to an array of specific objects?